# sonar codequality batches in Bitbucket repo readme

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I want to show code quality badges like Reliability, Maintainability, Code Coverage and build status from Sonar and Jenkins into Bitbucket Readme file.

I'm using Bitbucket Server 5.13 and Sonarqube 7.4.

Can someone please help if there are ready made add-onsq or if there is any workarounds we can achieve this.

Comment: This should help you with your question: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/2987

Comment: i think the link provide solution for bitbucket pipeline, but i'm using Jenkins pipeline, checking out bitbucket code to jenkins and integrated sonar scanner to perform static code analysis. Can we get metrics directly from Sonar into Readme.md of a repo in Bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i have achieved this by using SVG badges.
https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-badges